# Problems with formatting date with moment.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was creating weather app in React by using Open Weather Map API and as you know, API gives us data on 5 day/3 hour forecast. Moreover, since API by default uses a GMT Unix timestamp format I decided to format it into "MM-DD-YYYY" to work with date easily. But the problem is when I try to further convert "MM-DD-YYYY" into LT format in moment.js I lose time date in date and by default all time gets 12:00 AM. Is it true that if we try to convert original GMT Unix timestamp format into "MM-DD-YYYY" and then further convert "MM-DD-YYYY" into "LT" we will lose time that was in GMT Unix timestamp?

[image]

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import SearchBox from "./Containers/SearchBox/SearchBox";
import Header from "./Components/Header/Header";
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import CardContainer from "./Containers/CardContainer/CardContainer";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./Components/About/About";
import axios from "axios";
import WeatherDay from "./Components/WeatherDay/WeatherDay";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: null
  };

  getTitle = location => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${location}&APPID=7ad09d078633b652ecef8587a337639e&units=metric`
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          title: res
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className={styles.App}>
          <Fragment>
            <Header title={"Weather App"} />
            <Switch>
              <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                render={props => (
                  <Fragment>
                    <div className="container">
                      <SearchBox getRequest={this.getTitle} />
                    </div>
                    <main className={styles.mainContent}>
                      <h1 className={styles.cityWeather}>
                        {this.state.title && this.state.title.data.city.name}
                      </h1>
                      <CardContainer
                        weatherData={
                          this.state.title && this.state.title.data.list
                        }
                      />
                    </main>
                  </Fragment>
                )}
              />

              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route
                path="/day/:date"
                render={props => (
                  <WeatherDay {...props} title={this.state.title} />
                )}
              />
            </Switch>
            <Footer copyright={"Copyright 2018"} />
          </Fragment>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


import React from "react";
import "./WeatherDay.module.css";
import moment from "moment";
const WeatherDay = props => { // This is the component where I have a problem with conversion
  const allDays =
    props.title &&
    props.title.data.list.map(item => ({
      date: moment(new Date(item.dt_txt)).format("MM-DD-YYYY"),
      main: item.main,
      weather: item.weather
    }));
  const chosenDate = props.match.params.date;

  const day =
    props.title &&
    allDays.filter((item, index) => {
      return item.date === chosenDate;
    });

  const mir =
    props.title &&
    day.map(item => { //Here I am trying to convert "MM/DD/YYYY" into "LT" and lose time info
      return <p>{moment(new Date(item.date)).format("LT")}</p>;
    });

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-2"></div>
      {mir}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WeatherDay;
```

[image]

Comment: Provide the sampe date which you are converting.

Comment: @ravibagul91, ok added I have issue with conversion in WeatherDay component which is down below in code block above. Thank you:)

Comment: @ravibagul91, please let me know if something is not clear:). I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Dickens, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ravibagul91, hi dude, I tried and no result:(. Let me explain the logic, I intentionally  used "MM-DD-YYYY" to remove time from date. Since open weather map provides 5/3 json, I wanted to get all data depending on what day user clicks, e.g, if user clicks on wednesday then all data about wednesday should be retrived. If I do not remove time then only ONE data will be given to me but I want all of the data of chosen day.

Comment: @ravibagul91, Moreover, to continue, after I got data on chosen day, then I want to kinda restore time and show weather data per 3 hour. Please look at the picture I will add it now. From my debugger

Comment: @ravibagul91, sorry perhaps you are a bit confused :D. TLDR, I converted into "MM-DD-YYYY" to get all data of chosen day then after I got all data I want to format it back so that I had time data and show it to user. Thus I used LT format but it gave me 12 :00 AM for all data but it should be for first data 3:00AM, the second data 6:00AM for third 9:00AM.... Please let me know you are still confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up sth. here. You should not use a time string to actually calculate it, only change the format for your date, but keep the actual moment object for further calculations. This way you always have the right time and dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you formatting on already formatted date. You should sustain the moment object instead of formatted date.

You should format the date only at the time of rendering. While passing we pass `moment` object.

Example

```
let parsed = moment(new Date())
let format1 = parsed.format('MM-DD-YYYY')
let format2 = parsed.format('LT')
console.log(format1) // 09-20-2019
console.log(format2) // 3:43 PM
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: hi dude,  TLDR, I converted into "MM-DD-YYYY" to get all data of chosen day(if I do not do that then I will get only one data of certain day) then after I got all data I want to format it back so that I had time data and show it to user. Thus I used LT format but it gave me 12 :00 AM for all data but it should be for first data 3:00AM, the second data 6:00AM for third 9:00AM

Comment: Apply formatting - moment(item.date).format('..) === chosenDate inside allDays.filter, this way you will not have to convert into string and can pass moment object everywhere. Second approach could be to add another property of parsed moment object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to this,

```
date: moment(new Date(item.dt_txt)).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
```

When you convert date as above it strips out time from it and you get simple date.

It should be this,

```
date: moment(new Date(item.dt_txt)).format("MM-DD-YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bl8kh2)